# How can I replace a kitchen cabinet hinge with no visible screws?

Tags: kitchens, hinges

My kitchen cabinet hinge is broken. I want to replace it, but not really sure how because it is attached to the cabinet door without any screw ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykxU8l.jpg)). Anyone know a proper way to detach the hinge?

[image: Kitchen cabinet hinge with no screw]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, this is a special hinge that doesn't require screw in the door flap. Similiar to the one shown in this video http://youtu.be/NCpoKo2INog

That metal plate is a clip that can be easily pried off, by using screwdriver for example. After the clip is opened, the "tweezers" (red circles in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uPDd.png)) will loosen and the hinge can now be easily detached from the door.

[image: Hinge]

Answer (score 6):

I believe that flat metal plate against the door is a cover that will pry off.  You'll find screws underneath.

Comment: How can I remove the metal plate?

Comment: Exactly right, the trim cover has to come off first.  Use a thin flat blade screwdriver to get under it. Probably under the back edge would work well.

Comment: You should get a plastic pry tool set - they make a product like that to remove car trim so you don't have to worry (so much) about marking up the actual cabinet door with the screw driver.  Something like one of these - http://www.harborfreight.com/4-piece-nylon-pry-bar-installer-kit-95214.html

Answer (score 2):

Try using a kit like this to pop off the metal plate, then you can find screws to remove it from the door.  The advantage of the nylon kit is that it won't mark up the door (or hinge).

http://www.harborfreight.com/4-piece-nylon-pry-bar-installer-kit-95214.html

[image]